# How to join two tables when one has multiple values

Tags: sql, left-join

Why won't these two tables join correctly with the following SQL?

```
SELECT o.*
FROM opening_hours o
LEFT JOIN farms f ON o.farm_id = f.id
WHERE f.id = 69
```

[image: Tables]

Comment: Are you sure that the images correspond to the tables as you posted?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: Please explain what not working means.

Comment: So the table farms has columns start_hour and end_hour?

Comment: By not working I mean the result I get is simply "table: farms" rather than opening hours being joined to it

Comment: @forpas That's correct yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM opening_hours o
LEFT JOIN farms f ON o.farm_id = f.id
WHERE f.id = 69
```

creates a useless join, it's equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM opening_hours WHERE farm_id = 69
```

because it is a left join that selects columns only from the *left* table.
If you want to get something from this join, select columns also from the *right* table like:

```
SELECT o.*, f.*
FROM opening_hours o
LEFT JOIN farms f ON o.farm_id = f.id
WHERE f.id = 69
```

Comment: This works thanks, though I'm not sure why I need both SELECT o.* and f.*

Comment: o.* and f.* stand for **all columns**

Comment: select * is usually a bad practice to begin with. Unless it's an ad-hoc query, you should explicitly define the columns.

Comment: @user1228907 I still believe that you mixed the images and the names of the tables. The table **farms** is the one with the column `farm_name`